# How does one map many routes in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring

An AngularJS site with a Spring Boot backend has numerous `public` url patterns in addition to a `secure` section.  All the `public` url patterns fall in the model `mydomain.com/public1`, `mydomain.com/public2`, `mydomain.com/public3`, and so on, while all the secure content will be inside the `mydomain.com/secure` url pattern like `mydomain.com/secure/one_of_many_urls`.  The problem is that the sample app I am starting with has separate modules for every route.  This would become hard to maintain with **n** routes.

**How can I set the code up so that all the `public1`, `public2`, `public3`, `public_n` routes share a single controller?**

Here is the current directory structure.  I would like for the `public1` directory to turn into `public` and be able to map as many specific url patterns as I want to put into it:

[image]

In addition, my `public1.js` is currently empty as follows:

```
angular.module('public1', []).controller('public1', function($scope, $http) {

});
```

The link to the `public1` route is handled in a navigation bar in `index.html` as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Angular</title>
<!-- To produce natural routes (without the #), you need an extra <base/> element in the header of the HTML in index.html, and you need to change the links in the menu bar to remove the fragments ("#").  There are also changes in a spring controller and in the main js module. -->
<base href="/" />
<link href="css/angular-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body ng-app="hello" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
    <div ng-controller="navigation" class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
            <li ng-class="{active:tab('home')}"><a href="/">home</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab('message')}"><a href="/message">message</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab('public1')}"><a href="/public1">public1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/login">login</a></li>
            <li ng-show="authenticated()"><a href="" ng-click="logout()">logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-view class="container"></div>
    <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/auth/auth.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/home/home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/message/message.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/public1/public1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/navigation/navigation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/hello.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And `public1.html` is:

```
<h1>Public 1</h1>
<div>
    <p>This will be a public url pattern.</p>
</div>
```

**How do I change the code below so that a scaling `n` number of public routes can efficiently share the same controller?**  Each public_n route will have their own images, but would share js logic, if they have any js logic.

**I found the following, but where would one put it in the code above, and how would a person link everything to it without resorting to leaving it in `hello.js`?**

```
.when('/public1', {
    templateUrl: 'js/public/public1.html'
}
.when('/public2', {
    templateUrl: 'js/public/public2.html'
}
.when('/public3', {
    templateUrl: 'js/public/public3.html'
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I change the code below so that a scaling n number of public
>   routes can efficiently share the same controller?

You can **Associate one Controller to Many Routes (Views)** just assigning it to more routes in your **$routeProvider** as follows:

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider
  .when('/public1', {
    templateUrl: 'js/public/public1.html',
    controller: 'myController'
  })
  .when('/public2', {
    templateUrl: 'js/public/public2.html',
    controller: 'myController'
  })
  .when('/public3', {
    templateUrl: 'js/public/public3.html',
    controller: 'myController'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
})
```

You can also **Set a Controller Alias** as follows:

```
.when('/public1', {
    templateUrl: 'js/public/public1.html',
    controller: 'myController',
    controllerAs: 'myCtrl'
})
```

> I found the following, but where would one put it in the code above,
>   and how would a person link everything to it without resorting to
>   leaving it in hello.js?

If I got your question, you just need to put the **$routeProvider** in a separated **routeProvider.js** file and include it in your **index.html**. Same thing for your controller/controllers.

I suggest you to take a look at:

- [AngularJS Controllers Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)
- [AngularJS $routeProvider Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)
- [Follow the first lesson of - CodeSchool - Staying Sharp with AngularJS](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/staying-sharp-with-angular-js/level/1/wrap-up)
- [EggHead.io AngularJS Screencasts](https://egghead.io/technologies/angularjs)

And also take a look at those Q/A on StackOverflow:

- [Using one controller for many coherent views across multiple HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312226/angular-using-one-controller-for-many-coherent-views-across-multiple-http-requ)
- [Views sharing same controller, model data resets when changing view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210822/angular-js-views-sharing-same-controller-model-data-resets-when-changing-view)
- [Controlling multiple views in one controller in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061307/controlling-multiple-views-in-one-controller-in-angularjs)
- [Can I use one controller updating two views in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447346/can-i-use-one-controller-updating-two-views-in-angularjs)

I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: So then does your first block of code above go into routeProvider.js?  And how does hello.js change to accommodate this?

Comment: Yes, it belongs to routeProvider.js. If your hello.js is supposed to incorporate the route logic, you just need to copy paste and re-arrange on your needs my code.

Comment: Thank you and +1 (hopefully a hat too) for adding insight.